# Already have data/db in root, but still can't run MongoDB on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb

As the title said, I do have the folder data inside my root directory on Mac OS X and inside that the folder db. I've installed mongodb with homebrew, and everything seems to work except this. I also have all the permissions for both folders. When i run the command "mongod" this is the output:

```
 mongod --help for help and startup options  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.641+0200 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16414 port=27017      dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Djangos-MacBook-Air.local  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten]   
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of    files is 256, should be at least 1000  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.3  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local      13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-    2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] options: {}  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable    to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit:   
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening  sockets...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.642+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.643+0200 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished  
 2014-07-28T12:59:39.643+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now`
```

I would be glad if someone could help me, because I've googled A LOT and haven't find any solution.

Comment: Is this question related to programming?

Comment: @trojanfoe I would say so, in kind of a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend not to create data folder on root of your Mac OS X. If you do so then you will have to run mongod as root. So it is better if you make data folder inside your own home directory, which would be /Users/yourname/ .

Now, let me tell you the problem. It says, 'Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock'. That means it is not able to write to the location. So the solution is - either run mongod as root or change the location of data folder to your own home location where you have permissions to write.

Comment: or you can change the permission of current folder as well.

Comment: @displayName But i figured out the error, I'm not on my regular user because the terminal on my regular user does not work. So for some reason on this user, it doesn't work. If i were to change back to my regular user, it wouldn't recognize any command, for example sudo and curl.